# Mysql utf8mb4 connection string (Node.js, serverless-mysql package)

Tags: mysql, connection-string, utf8mb4

I've changed my Mysql defaults to utf8mb4, however emojis are still getting refused by mysql.

```
Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\xA9</...'
```

I'm thinking this might be because of my connection string.

I'm connecting and sending queries to Mysql with the [serverless-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-mysql) package, which is based on the [mysql package](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options).

I think I should be able to create a connection as so:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection('mysql://user:pass@host/db?debug=true&charset=BIG5_CHINESE_CI&timezone=-0700');
```

However I'm not entirely sure what my connection string should be for me to support **utf8mb4** and be able to save emojis to my database. What should my string look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "refused"?

Comment: @NicoHaase Mysql responds with `Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\xA9</...'`

Comment: (I edited the OP to make that more clear, sorry about the confusion)

Comment: Have you tried `utf8mb4` instead of `BIG5_CHINESE_CI`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the package itself supports adding a setting for charset. So I changed my config to:

```
const db = mysql({
  config: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    charset: 'utf8mb4'
  }
});
```

And I can now send emojis to Mysql without errors.

Comment: This answer is going to be very confusing for whoever googles here in the future. Are you trying to say that the library doesn't support to set connection encoding as string? The [source code](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/283425b44bc7a310bf6613d0e112d89080516e55/lib/ConnectionConfig.js#L7) for either formats appears to be the same?

Comment: Not sure why it would be confusing. Both `serverless-mysql` and `mysql` allow to set a config to specify the connection charset. Both packages also support connection encoding as a string, which I thought I needed to use to specify charset, but it's much easier to set it within config.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps to follow in order to avoid this error on Loopback projects.

##### Step1 : On Database side

You must change the database and specific tables/columns CHARSET to `utf8mb4` and select any [utf8mb4]'s collation (eg. utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

##### Step 2: On Loopback Side

In the package [loopback-connector-mysql](https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-connector-mysql), there is a parameter `collation` that determines the charset for the connection. Default is `utf8_general_ci`.

So your database config will looks like :

```
const config = {
  name: 'ecofretransitDb',
  connector: 'mysql',
  ...
  collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' // Add this line. It must be aligned with the collation that you choose for your database and table
};
```